# Were the porgs rotoscoped puffins?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Something I noticed about porgs is that they have a small resemblance to puffins:
[image: image of a puffin]

We see them flapping into their nests, and the porgs flap very similar to puffins, so did the director rotoscope the puffins that naturally lived in that area to look like porgs?

Comment: Onto your question, it seems more than likely that they were based off of puffins, I thought that as soon as they first appeared on screen.

Comment: I kind of doubt they literally rotoscoped puffins (that is, traced live action footage of puffins to animate the porgs.) Perhaps the animators studied puffin footage as they were animating, however.

Comment: Just an interesting fact: the island in the movie is a real island called Skellig Michael, and there are actual puffins living there. I'd be surprised if that didn't somehow inspire the person who created the Porgs.

Comment: Porgs are mutated descendants of Tribbles.. https://giphy.com/gifs/star-wars-the-last-jedi-porg-3ohhwldDdBZENAlfEs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes and no. According to StarWars.com, the porgs were a creation of the effects workshop. Some were stop-motion puppets, some were animatronic, some were hand-operated and some were entirely digital. Although they were *inspired* by puffins, there's no indication that they were directly rotoscoped onto them.

> **StarWars.com:** *In the D23 behind-the-scenes reel, we see that porgs (or at least a porg) were made through practical effects.*
>
> **Pablo Hidalgo:** *The porgs are realized through a variety of effects, depending on what’s needed. Sometimes they’re puppets, with
> the puppeteers digitally removed from the shot. Other times, they’re
> entirely CG.*
>
> <sub><sup>[INTRODUCING PORGS, THE CUTE NEW CREATURES FROM STAR WARS: THE LAST JEDI](http://www.starwars.com/news/introducing-porgs-the-cute-new-creatures-from-star-wars-the-last-jedi)</sup></sub>

That being said, porgs were CGI'd ***over*** the Skellig Island puffins in the long shots, removing the need to digitally remove them.

> **StarWars.com:** *I want to start off with porgs! To begin, can you set the scene for how you started working on them?*
>
> **Jake Lunt Davies:** *Within our group there are four concept designers, so we tend to get a brief en masse, and we go away and draw our things, and some people’s ideas will sort of win out and be carried on through. We all kind of carry on pitching in as we go along, so sometimes they’re an amalgamation of various people’s ideas or, as I say, one person will hit the nail on the head and we’ll run with that. So we were briefed. From what I gathered, Rian [Johnson] had gone to shoot this sequence on Skellig Michael, which is the real island location that stands in for Ahch-To, and that island is covered in puffins. It’s a wildlife preserve and everywhere you look there are hundreds of birds dotted around the landscape. From what I gathered, Rian, in a positive spin on this, was looking at how can he work with this. You can’t remove them. You physically can’t get rid of them. And **digitally removing them is an issue and a lot of work, so let’s just roll with it, play with it. And so I think he thought, “Well, that’s great, let’s have our own indigenous species.”** We’d already started work on the Caretakers, which again was a brief from Rian. We’d just been told “puffin people.” Yeah, there was going to be this race of people and puffins again were a source of inspiration for Rian. The puffins were sort of a big influence on everything, really.*
>
> <sub><sup>[DESIGNING STAR WARS: THE LAST JEDI, PART 1: HOW PORGS WERE HATCHED](http://www.starwars.com/news/designing-star-wars-the-last-jedi-part-1-how-porgs-were-hatched)</sup></sub>

[image]

Answer (score 4):

https://www.rte.ie/entertainment/2017/1012/911748-star-wars/

> Director Rian Johnson told Entertainment Weekly about creating the characters, saying: "If you go to Skellig at the right time of year, it’s just covered in puffins, and they’re the most adorable things in the world."
>
> "So when I was first scouting there, I saw these guys, and I was like, oh, these are part of the island. And so the porgs are in that realm."

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question of if puffins were rotoscope to create the porgs.

Comment: Also you should merge your accounts, you clearly show interest in the site. Why not become an active member again?

Comment: @Edlothiad - I suspect he has his reasons why he keeps using disposable accounts.

Comment: This answer would be improved by quoting the source of the quote; http://ew.com/movies/2017/08/09/star-wars-last-jedi-porgs-caretakers/ rather than quoting someone quoting the quote